# android timeout error

Tags: android

I have constructed my app and have tested it on the real device but for some reason it is timing out. I am not sure why.

Here is Error log:

```
[2012-05-29 09:49:42 - androidGUI] Android Launch!
[2012-05-29 09:49:42 - androidGUI] adb is running normally.
[2012-05-29 09:49:42 - androidGUI] Performing alex.android.development.AndroidGUIActivity activity launch
[2012-05-29 09:49:42 - androidGUI] Automatic Target Mode: using device '3834522F2C1E00EC'
[2012-05-29 09:49:42 - androidGUI] Uploading androidGUI.apk onto device '3834522F2C1E00EC'
[2012-05-29 09:49:48 - androidGUI] Failed to install androidGUI.apk on device '3834522F2C1E00EC': timeout
[2012-05-29 09:49:48 - androidGUI] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: increasing the efault adb timeout solved your problem or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try change the **DDMS adb connect time out** :

> in Eclipse -> Windows -> Preference -> Android -> DDMS

Change the **ADB Connection time out(ms)** bigger whatever you want.

If it also the problem, you can try:

```
adb kill-server
adb devices
```

Then, refresh the device(s).

Answer (score 2):

This is because the emulator is disconnecting from the DDMS of the eclipse...

so to reconnect it run the command

> adb devices

which will restart the adb...

Hope it works

Comment: you may be onto something here.  The timestamps show about 6 seconds between start and failure.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the ADB connection timeout. I think it defaults that to 5000ms and changed mine to 10000ms i was able to get rid of that problem. If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through **Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android.**

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Are there by any chance spaces in the directory path to your APK.  I have seen several people have this kind of trouble due to that.  (Often the mistake is to put eclipse in `Program Files` and the workspace inside eclipse.)  Try copying your apk file out of the workspace and to C: and upload it with `adb push.`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to uncheck the "wait for the debugger to attach" in the development options of the device.