# Adb.exe (Android Debug Bridge) Can't Install .apk

Tags: java, android, emulation, adb

Whenever I use the adb to install an Android application on either my emulator or device,
it says "Failed to install ***.apk on device timeout.

I tried every solution that was offered in identical questions:

- I changed the ADB connection timeout from 5000 --> 60000
- I restarted ADB
- I restarted the computer.

However, none of these methods seem to work. I'm running the ADB on Windows Vista 32 bit.
Is Windows Vista the problem? ADB can install apks when run on my Windows 7 computer.
The only reason I can't use Windows 7 is because its processor is too slow (the emulator runs at 2 fps)

By the way, when I used the 'adb devices' command in the command line, it seems that 
the ADB recognizes my phone or emulator. For some reason, it can't install an .apk
or push or pull files.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've experienced before. It tends to occur (for me) when I'm using a generic USB cable or am not plugged in properly. There really are many things that could be wrong. For example, you may need to restart your device, you may need to try a different USB port. These kinds of thing don't have a definitive solution.

Comment: That's not the issue because the adb can't install on BOTH the emulator and a real device. Also, I already tried different cables but they all don't work. I agree that these things don't have a definite solution because there seems to be very little documentation as to how to troubleshoot adb problems

Comment: The timeout is fairly long as it is but try making it longer and going AFK for a bit. I'd also suggest checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775603/android-error-failed-to-install-apk-on-device-timeout and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115899/failed-to-install-due-to-timeout-in-emulator

Comment: The reason that I have created a new thread is b/c I tried all of the proposed solutions in other threads and they have all failed. I'm going to increase the timeout to 1000000(1000 seconds) and see if that works. I'll notify you

Comment: What version of the ADT plugin and eclipse are you using?

Comment: Well apparently, in Windows Vista, you have to be logged into an administrator account in order to get the ADB to work. The reason it was failing to install was because I was not using an admin account. Thank you BackpackOnHead for helping anyways! Much appreciated.