# Android: Timed out error while waiting for emulator to come online in mac?

Tags: java, android, macos, android-6.0-marshmallow

I found a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115899/failed-to-install-due-to-timeout-in-emulator). I have a simple app that displays a button on screen. I use Mac OS, latest android studio, and Java 8. I can launch android without the app, but get `Android: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online` error with the app. The simulator setting is 1 GB RAM, 512 VM heap, Nexus 5X, marshmallow (android 23). How can I identify the problem and get app to run without reinstall everything?

From console:

```
/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
```

From app console:

```
06/10 19:25:48: Launching app
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Changing Graphics option on the AVD Manager to Software or try all the combinations.

Answer (score 0):

**Look for an emulator that suits you.**

As you may see in Android Virtual Device Manager (AVD), you can download SDK devices and tools for them and create a new AVD. Then hit that checkbox marked *Show downloadable system images*.

After that, click a random one, download it if you need, and launch it once it is done.

If that suits you then that should be it. Note that if you're using the 6.0 AVD it won't work for many computers so that might also be the problem.